# I am not able to use bottom tab navigator on my react native project. Any one know why?

Tags: react-native, bottomnavigationview

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
```

This is the erro message.

```
Unable to resolve "react-native-screens" from "node_modules\@react-navigation\bottom-tabs\src\views\BottomTabView.tsx"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install

`npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs` or if you used yarn package manager,

`yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

Have you updated the pod file if you added this package?

```
cd ios 
pod install
```

Comment: yes I did install  @react-navigation/bottom-tabs pod file?

Comment: I dont have IOS folder. I dont know why. I am using expo app in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Install the following packages

```
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens
```

Check the docs
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Hope this helps!